# Tesseract 4 with two languages

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have following image: [image]

When I call tesseract with `-l eng+rus` (or `-l rus+eng`) I get this result:

```
Повар спрашивает повара - 200 ВОВ!
```

As you can see Russian part of the text is recognized alright but RUB part is wrong because Tesseract thinks that it's Russian text as well as far as I understand. Even though confidence for `BOB` word is only 34, looks like Tesseract is not trying to use English. Is there a way of fixing it besides of separating this text into two groups and running Tesseract separately on them? (I know that the second part if always English but the first one can be either English or Russian).

P.S I tried using Cyrillic script trained data (Cyrillic.traineddata) but the result is pretty much the same (`Повар спрашивает повара - 200 ВЏВ!`)

Comment: instead of trying eng+rus, could you try Latin with Russian and see if it helps the accuracy as Latin is a culmination of all languages that use the Latin script? -l lat+rus

Comment: @Jamesm Unfortunately it gives pretty the same results.

Comment: Please provide the full command line you're using. Do you have both eng and rus trained data in your traineddata directory? Another thing to check is whether "RUB" is actually in the eng word list you trained with.

Comment: @mnistic I'm using `-l` as the only extra parameter for tesseract. Yes, I have both rus and eng traineddata (the default ones, not trained myself). What is the way of checking that? I'd guess it has this word since it's recognized when I use -l eng only or when whole text is eng text (without mix of Russian).

Comment: OK... it looks like the default word list does have it in there: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata/master/eng/eng.wordlist Currently AFAIK the only way to change the weight given to one language is by swapping the two languages (i.e. `eng+rus`) but you're already doing that. The English section may just not be relatively big enough for the recognizer to give English more weight. You can try playing with the different penalty settings, but your best bet may be sectioning the image into two yourself, after the numerical section.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are using proper syntax for multi language identification but the results clearly show that 'BOB' is being misclassified. You do one thing first run this text only in eng language mode and see the results, it will most probably read BOB as proper text. Then after this check change the default model being used for eng text recognition. Hope it will make same adjustments. And if not then you will have to bear with these results, because tesseract is not made to give 100% results.